# jquery autoSearch watermark

Tags: jquery, watermark

I'm using the jquery plugin wordFilter: http://people.apache.org/~gmonroe/wordFilter/index.html which gives the autoSearch function, which allows for automatically filtering a list of elements based on text typed into a text_field.

It works great, but I was hoping to also have a text_field watermark in there if there is no text entered.  this text unfortunately causes the autoSearch to trigger.  Of course, I don't want this, I want it to be ignored until the user actually types.

Does anyone have experience using an autoSearch type text field with watermarking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this effect pretty easily. Instead of immediately adding the autoSearch feature to a field, I added after the first time a user clicked on the field.

Here are the relevant chunks of code:

CSS: set a watermark color

```
.autoSearch {
    color: #999;
}
```

HTML: give the textbox the autoSearch class. I use a searchclass attribute to 
specify the search box will search over

```
<input type="text" class="field autoSearch" searchclass="assign-filter" id="assign-search"/>
```

Javascript: clear the box and remove the autoSearch class when you click. Add the autosearch functionality

```
$('.autoSearch').click(function() {
        $(this).val('');
        $(this).removeClass('autoSearch');
        $(this).autoSearch('.'+$(this).attr('searchclass')); 
    });
```

Comment: the click event will not fire if the user tabs to the textbox and so the watermark will not be removed, Instead you should use the focus event.

Answer (score 0):

the click event will not fire if the user tabs to the textbox and so the watermark will not be removed, Instead you should use the focus event.

```
$('.autoSearch').focus(function() {
        $(this).val('');
        $(this).removeClass('autoSearch');
        $(this).autoSearch('.'+$(this).attr('searchclass')); 
    });
```